# Python: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Have the following piece of code through which I am trying to plot a graph:

```py
df:
     date        qty
0  2016-01-01   21.523810
1  2016-02-01   20.476190
2  2016-03-01   20.523810
3  2016-04-01   26.666667
4  2016-05-01   
...
```

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 8 # width 10, height 8
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})

ax = df.plot(x='date', y='qty', style='bx-', grid=True)
```

but getting the following error message:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'

Not getting from where this float error is coming. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is convert periods to datetimes before ploting:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.to_timestamp()
```

Also for me working your solution, maybe you can try upgrade to last version of pandas/matplotlib.